# ASP.NET tables and identity tables containing duplicate data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Entity Framework 6.0.0.0.

I am working on an ASP.NET web application (Web API). When I see my database created by Entity Framework, the tables shown below like ASP.NET User & Application Users which have some duplicate data. Also, in `IdentityUserRoles` and `ASPNETUserRoles` also having duplicate data.

I don't want to keep these duplicate tables mainly want to continue with ASP.NET tables not identity tables. How can I achieve this, and what do I need to do? Why did these duplicate tables with the same data get created?

Below is User Model I am using :-

```
public class User 
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string application_user_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("application_user_id")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser applicationuser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? end_date { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests{ get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: your mapping is wrong so either, move to default name and delete old or configure to use other name, defaults is AspNet prefix.

Comment: where I need to look into?which mapping you mean?

Comment: how did you get identity there... that mapping, easiest for you is to delete identity prefix ones... and just use AspNet

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is to inherete the properties of the identity table in your tables.
To make it clear you just need to change your model into something like this:

```
public class user : IdentityUser
{
...
}
```

this way the columns in identity user will be added to the user table, in addition to your personnalized columns of the user table, I'm not sure if I made my answer clear enough but I will put here a link if you want to learn more about how to personnalize the identity tables : [Custom Identity model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: In your database you will have just the user table